# Distance between two points in one pipeline mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I must calculate the distance between two points in the most possible optimized way by id. But at first my query calculates the distance between the whole dataset before matching the right point

the data looks like:

```
[
{_id: 0, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 1, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 2, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 3, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 4, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
]
```

before the query happens I pre-fetch some pairs of nodes like this:

```
// ...
const node1 = await client.nodes_collection.findOne({
   _id: %{node1},
});

const node2 = await client.nodes_collection.findOne({
   _id: %{node2},
});
```

> Even tho only one is needed to perform distance query the other one will be used to some other types of queries

And the query is being performed like

```
let pipeline = [
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: node1.location.coordinates,
      },
      distanceField: 'distance',
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: node2._id,
    },
  },
];

let aggregate = client.nodes_collection.aggregate(pipeline);

let result = await aggregate.toArray();
```

I already tried to match the node2._id before $geoNear, but it crashes all the way

```
MongoServerError: $geoNear was not the first stage in the 
pipeline after optimization. Is optimization disabled or inhibited?
```

Comment: I am afraid you can't do anything in this case. GeoNear can only be used in the first stage of the pipeline. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: `$geoNear` has a `query` option. How about creating a compound index with the location field (unsure if that's `location` or `distance` based on your description) first and `_id` second, and then remove the `$match` by placing that filter inside of the `query` option?

Comment: @user20042973 tried this out but it performs the same. I don't know why, for large databases it can take more than an hour to calculate the distance between two points

Comment: The single aggregation takes an hour or some additional operation/work? Share the `"allPlansExecution"` verbosity mode of `explain` for the aggregation

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have estimated the time wrong. I'm testing a smaller A (131,675 nodes) and a medium database B (13,714,468).
A = 1 sec/pair calculation 
B = 3 minutes/pair calculation
and goes on for larger ones

The goal is a 265,780,749 nodes database (in that one the one hour query or something around may be happening), but It reaches time limite for that one. For comparison I'm performing other types of queries also manipulating spatial data, but they take at max some seconds to complete each cálculos. [explain aggr](https://gist.github.com/julipinto/dba0d6148ead3701cc58a541805f1ec7)